# Speed up apt-get update by removing known ignored Translation-en

Tags: 12.04, apt

I've mirrored some ubuntu repositories to a an internal repository using apt-mirror however due to https://serverfault.com/questions/93437/apt-mirror-does-not-mirror-the-i18n-directory i get the following:

```
Ign https://internalrepo precise-updates/main Translation-en
Ign https://internalrepo precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign https://internalrepo precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign https://internalrepo precise-updates/universe Translation-en
```

Now i'm trying to speed up as there are quite a few of these that slow down the `apt-get update` on our machines.

Is there any way I can tell the `sources.list.d` files or `apt-get` to don't even attempt to get these (I guess this would speed it up more than hitting an ignore)?

Using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Indeed it is, apologies for the duplicate post, my previous searches didn't render much. For those landing here in the future I will add the correct solution below.

Comment: Problem is that somehow now I get `Err https://internalrepo Packages` (doesn't show when I comment the previous solution)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding the fallowing line:

```
Acquire::Languages "none";
```

at the end of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude` (use `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00aptitude` in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) to edit this file).

After I did this, `sudo apt-get update` is running faster.

Comment: you can speed up even more if you download the apt cache in parallel, see: https://www.leggiero.uk/post/speed-up-apt-get-update-with-parallel/