# apt-get ignores all packages with "Translation-en_US"

Tags: 10.04, apt

Having a problem on an EC2 Ubuntu Lucid instance where if I run `(sudo) apt-get update` all packages with `Translation-en_US` are ignored.

```
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release.gpg
Ign http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates Release
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Packages
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Packages
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Sources
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Sources
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Packages
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Packages
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Sources
Hit http://ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/txwikinger/php5.2/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Sources
```

Just trying to get a little more context around the "ignore", and why it's only ignoring for `Translation-en_US`

Answer (score 3):

That means that the update process had checked that particulary repository list, and yours is up-to-date, so, for this is ignored.  Moreover, the ignored repository lists are not the same at every update.

If you want to pass over these ignored packages and speed up your update, follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/300078/147044).